# how to create a serverless endpoint in sagemaker via cloudformation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-sagemaker

cloudformation template below creates a sagemaker model and an endpoint configuration. my goal is to test serverless inference in sagemaker , but when i added the ServerlessConfig attribute to the endpoint config resource based on aws documentation , i get an error - "Property validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in {/} [ServerlessConfig]]. any ideas?

```
SageMakerModel:
    Type: AWS::SageMaker::Model
    Properties: 
      Containers: 
        -
          Image: !Ref ImageURI
          ModelDataUrl: !Ref ModelData
          Environment: {"SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM": "inference.py", "SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY": !Ref ModelData}
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref RoleArn


SageMakerEndpointConfig:
    Type: "AWS::SageMaker::EndpointConfig"
    Properties:
      ServerlessConfig: 
        -
          MaxConcurrency: 5
```

Comment: "get an error that" - what is the full error message?

Comment: @Marcin - updated question with exact error

Answer (score 0):

Hey please use this article and code as a reference: https://medium.com/towards-data-science/deploying-sagemaker-endpoints-with-cloudformation-b43f7d495640.

In the endpoint configuration resource make sure to adjust for the Serverless Options: MaxConcurrency and MemorySize rather than the instance count and type settings detailed for a real-time endpoint.